# Why declare a constant pointer using the const keyword when the reference (const pointer) is available?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

For example:

I could make a constant pointer, which points to an object that I can change through my pointer. The pointer cannot be reassigned:

```
MyObj const *ptrObj = MyObj2
```

Why would I use this over:

```
MyObj &ptrObj = MyObj2
```

Comment: You wouldn't because it doesn't compile as shown. Assuming `MyObj` is a type and `MyObj2` is an instance of `MyObj` you would still need a `&` there ...

Answer (score 4):

What you have there isn't a `const` pointer, it's a pointer to a `const` object - that is, the pointer can be changed but the object can't. A `const` pointer would be:

```
MyObj *const ptrObj = &MyObj2;
```

As to why you might prefer it over a reference, you might want the flexibility of using the `NULL` special value for something - you don't get that with a reference.

Answer (score 2):

You got it wrong. What you have is a *mutable* pointer to a *constant* object:

```
T const * p;
p = 0;            // OK, p isn't const
p->mutate();      // Error! *p is const
T const & r = *p; // "same thing"
```

What you really want is a *constant* pointer to *mutable* object:

```
T * const p = &x; // OK, cannot change p
T & r = x;        // "same thing"
p->mutate();      // OK, *p is mutable
```

Indeed, references are morally equivalent to constant pointers, i.e. `T &` vs `T * const`, and the constant version `T const &` vs `T const * const`.

If you insist on getting some advice, then I'd say, "don't use pointers".

Answer (score 1):

The important difference between a pointer and a reference is how many objects they may refer to. A reference always refers to exactly one object. A pointer may refer to zero (when the pointer is null), one (when the pointer was assigned the location of a single object) or n objects (when the pointer was assigned to some point inside an array).

The ability of pointers to refer to 0 to n objects means that a pointer is more flexible in what it can represent. When the extra flexibility of a pointer is not necessary it is generally better to use a reference. That way someone reading your code doesn't have to work out whether the pointer refers to zero, one or n objects.